# Is there any way to force the browser to NOT use Enterprise Mode in IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to develop a website that uses features not compatible with IE7/8, but the company-standard browser (IE11) we all use forces my page to use Enterprise Mode (which is effectively rendering with IE7/8).

Everything I've seen talks about fixing it on a high-level "site list" within the company, or making a browser not use Enterprise Mode locally (by modifying registry entries). One internally suggested approach was to use the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

...but it didn't work.

Is there any way I can force the client, from the server-side, to **not** use Enterprise mode?

Note: We are using Websphere 8.5 servers.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me - forcing the X-UA compatible header from IIS by modifying the application's web.config file as below (if you are using IIS as your webserver).

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <remove name="X-UA-Compatible" /> <!-- in case it was already set -->
            <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Unfortunately we don't use IIS :(

Comment: Most web servers provide a way to specify custom HTTP response headers.  Here's one way to do it in older versions of Apache: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc817573.aspx.  Your preferred search engine may help locate info for the server you do use.